# How to stub a JSON file with Sinon

Tags: tdd, sinon

I have a JSON file which I require in the following manner:

`const things = require('./path/to/things);`

I want to stub this file in a sandbox so it always returns a given fixture.

```
const fixture = {
  fake: "things"
}

const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

beforeEach(() => {
  sandbox.stub(things).returns(fixture);
});

afterEach(() => {
  sandbox.restore();
});
```

This lead to an error `returns is not a function`. I'm not sure about how to stub JSON with a sandbox. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stub only method calls. In this case the call is `require(...)`. I think you have two options:

1. Stub the require function.

   ```
   const sinon = require('sinon');
   const Module = require('module');
   const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
   sandbox.stub(Module.prototype, 'require').returns({fake:'things'});
   const things = require('./things/');
   console.log(JSON.stringify(things));
   ```

   Here's a repl link to the above: https://repl.it/repls/PessimisticSubtleHexagon
2. Make your system under test depend on `things` and inject it. That way you decouple the logic you want to test from the import statement.

Comment: Thank you. I went for the dependency injection method.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is using [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to allow `require` statement to return mock json.

```
// noCallThru() is used to prevent call to the real JSON
// @see https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire#preventing-call-thru-to-original-dependency

const proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru();

const fixture = {
  fake: "things"
}

const src = proxyquire('./source-file', { './path/to/things': fixture });

beforeEach(() => {
  // empty
});

afterEach(() => {
 // empty
});
```

Hope it helps